# http response got truncated in docker

Tags: docker, netty

I've built a http server using netty.  Everything is fine when it's running in my mac, but when I run it in a docker image, the http response always get truncated when great than 460k.

What's the problem will be?   Please help.

Comment: I'm using netty 5.0.0alpha2 .

Comment: Showing the Dockerfile and reproducible test may help.

Comment: Do you use aggregator to aggregate the http response or not?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use aggregator to aggregate the http response or not?  Take a look at the source code of HttpObjectDecoder.  It will chunk bigger http response no matter if the http message itself is transfer coding or not.

The default maxChunk size is 8k.And even readable bytes is enough, it will chunk it. see the code below:

`   case READ_FIXED_LENGTH_CONTENT: {
            int readLimit = actualReadableBytes();

```
        // Check if the buffer is readable first as we use the readable byte count
        // to create the HttpChunk. This is needed as otherwise we may end up with
        // create a HttpChunk instance that contains an empty buffer and so is
        // handled like it is the last HttpChunk.
        //
        // See https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/433
        if (readLimit == 0) {
            return;
        }

        int toRead = Math.min(readLimit, maxChunkSize);
        if (toRead > chunkSize) {
            toRead = (int) chunkSize;
        }
        ByteBuf content = readBytes(ctx.alloc(), buffer, toRead);
        chunkSize -= toRead;
```

`